# ¿Qué significa "nada del otro domingo"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, significado

Soy estudiante de español y un anglohablante nativo. Leí un ensayo o un articulo en linea en el que el autor escribió la frase "nada del otro domingo." Supongo que en inglés eso es "nothing from the other Sunday." ¿Qué significa eso? Me parece que esa frase quiere decir "nada especial" o "no es un gran reto" o una cosa parecida. ¿Es así?

Comment: Gracias por corregir la pregunta. No soy hispanohablante ni un estudiante avanzado, lol.

Comment: Curioso, siempre lo había oído con _nada del otro jueves_ , del cual hay una posible explicación en [_Ya está el listo que todo lo sabe_](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/el-curioso-e-historico-origen-de-la-expresion-no-es-nada-del-otro-jueves/) (sin referencias).

Comment: @fedorqui yo sé yo si fiarme. No da referencias y no explica que la expresión original es "cosa del otro jueves" ("hecho extraordinario"), como recoge el diccionario y como se ve en el CORDE con textos hasta del siglo XVII.

Comment: @Charlie exacto. Yo solía creer sus publicaciones a pies juntillas, pero tras comentarlo walen me di cuenta de que muchas veces cojean por su falta de referencias. A ver si [su usuario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/19503/alfred-l%C3%B3pez) vuelve y podemos consultarle más directamente qué fuentes maneja.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesante. La frase original y que se puede encontrar en muchos sitios es "no es nada del otro jueves". Ignoro por qué el autor habrá usado *domingo* en vez de *jueves*, pero no creo que eso cambie el significado de la expresión.

Efectivamente, como bien dices significa "no es algo que sea importante". Lo curioso es que si buscas la expresión en el diccionario, lo que encuentras es:

> **[cosa del otro jueves](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B3yTydM)**
>
> 1. f. coloq. Hecho extraordinario. U. en frs. de sent. negat.
> 2. f. coloq. Aquello que hace mucho tiempo que pasó.

La expresión "cosa del otro jueves" con el significado de "hecho extraordinario" se usa, como se indica, principalmente en frases de sentido negativo, es decir, del tipo "no es cosa del otro jueves". Cambiando las palabras simplemente queda como "esto no es nada del otro jueves" se dice que no hay nada extraordinario o de importancia en lo comentado.