# Origen de la expresión "cosa del otro jueves"

Tags: expresiones, significado, historia, españa

Gracias a una [reciente pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27238/12637) hemos descubierto que el diccionario recoge la expresión:

> **[cosa del otro jueves](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B3yTydM#6ltHZ4Z)**
>
> 1. f. coloq. Hecho extraordinario. U. en frs. de sent. negat.
> 2. f. coloq. Aquello que hace mucho tiempo que pasó.

Me interesa la primera acepción, que se especifica que se usa solo en frases de sentido negativo, es decir del tipo "no es cosa del otro jueves", para indicar que lo comentado no es nada extraordinario, aunque a veces sí que se usa en sentido positivo, como es el caso del ejemplo más antiguo encontrado:

> *Mi bisabuelo tuvo títeres en Sevilla, los más bien vestidos y acomodados de
>   retablo que jamás entraron en aquel pueblo. Era pequeño, no mayor que del codo a la mano, que dél a sus títeres sólo había diferencia de hablar por cerbatana o sin ella. Lo que es decir **la arenga o plática era cosa del otro jueves**. Una lengua tenía arpada como tordo, una boca grande, que algunas veces pensaban que había de voltear por la boca. Daba tanto gusto el verle hacer la arenga titerera, que por oírle se iban desvalidas tras él fruteras, castañeras y turroneras, sin dejar en guarda de su tienda más que el sombrero o calentador.*
>
> Francisco López de Úbeda, "La pícara Justina", 1605 (España).

El Diccionario de Autoridades define la expresión como:

> La que es extraña, rara, ò pocas veces vista.

Quería buscar la definición de la expresión en el diccionario de Covarrubias, pero soy incapaz de encontrar la entrada para "jueves". El caso es que en su origen parece que la expresión significaba "cosa extraordinaria por poco habitual". No sé si esto concuerda con la explicación [que da Alfred López en su blog](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/el-curioso-e-historico-origen-de-la-expresion-no-es-nada-del-otro-jueves/) acerca de las comilonas de los jueves por la noche para poder hacer ayuno los viernes, dado que él analiza la expresión "no es nada del otro jueves".

Así pues, ¿cuándo se originó la expresión "cosa del otro jueves"? ¿Cuál fue su origen?

Tengo la teoría de que podría ser una variante de "cosa del otro mundo", dado que la expresión "[del otro mundo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Q5etWXp#9pZGGNW)" también significa "extraordinario o fuera de lo común". El DLE pone como ejemplos:

> Ese actor no es nada del otro mundo.
>   El premio tampoco parece cosa del otro mundo.

Nótese que en estas expresiones se podría perfectamente cambiar *mundo* por *jueves*. Y esta expresión es más antigua:

> *E el mercador que vio venir más de quarenta ombres todos vestidos de ábito de monte, e cada uno su sabueso por la traílla, e dellos algunos alanos e lebreles, fue muy espantado qué era aquello, ca a él **le parescía cosa del otro mundo** la vista destas gentes.*
>
> Pedro de Corral, "Crónica del rey don Rodrigo, postrimero rey de los godos (Crónica sarracina)", c 1430 (España).

¿Podría ser *jueves* un eufemismo para *mundo*?

Answer (score 2):

En [este blog](https://fraseomania.blogspot.com/2018/03/no-es-nada-del-otro-jueves.html) he encontrado una explicación similar, aunque más extensa, que la dada por [Alfred López](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/el-curioso-e-historico-origen-de-la-expresion-no-es-nada-del-otro-jueves/) que mencionas:

> Para comprender el significado original de la expresión ‘no ser nada del otro jueves’ hemos de remontarnos a los tiempos en que el ayuno y la abstinencia de comer carne era obligado los viernes de cada semana, sobre todo durante la época de Cuaresma. ... los fieles más pudientes solían atiborrarse de comer el día anterior, esto es el **jueves**, que pasó a ser sinónimo de jornada ideal para degustar abundantes exquisiteces, al menos quienes podían permitírselo. Por eso, comparar un hecho como cosa del otro jueves supuso lo mismo que calificarlo de excepcional y magnífico, mientras que, en negativo, si algo no era cosa del otro jueves  es que no estuvo a la altura de lo esperado.
>
> El DRAE recoge la locución ‘cosa del otro jueves’ para referirse coloquialmente a algo que pasó hace mucho tiempo, aunque ya nadie lo entiende así, sino que se usa para aludir a un hecho extraordinario, con la advertencia de que es más habitual en frases con sentido negativo, es decir, en su forma ‘nada del otro jueves’, restando importancia e interés a aquello a lo que se alude.